# Removing and adding roles mute command

Tags: discord.js

I've been making this mute command, the main thing is, it's only removing the main role. I want it to remove all roles and just only mute role and when unmuted the roles back again.
Here's what I've tried:

```
module.exports = {
    name: `jail`,
    description: "this is jail command!",
    execute(message, args){
        
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(member){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);{
                if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send("You cant jail person because you are not staff/co owner/owner");
            }
            let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(`791144820810842163` , `794825576602533898` , `791144908240060426` , `791144966474563624` , `791145298072305685` , `791145926344966185` , `791146191336505414` , `791146355552682034` , `792565793568587796` , `795357387794939904` , `795358283623432213` , `798804993468530699` , `791146747367653387`)
            let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Jailed'); 
 
            if (!args[1]) {
                memberTarget.roles.remove(`791144820810842163` , `794825576602533898` , `791144908240060426` , `791144966474563624` , `791145298072305685` , `791145926344966185` , `791146191336505414` , `791146355552682034` , `792565793568587796` , `795357387794939904` , `795358283623432213` , `798804993468530699` , `791146747367653387`);
                memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
                message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been Jailed`);
                return
            }
            memberTarget.roles.remove(`791144820810842163` , `794825576602533898` , `791144908240060426` , `791144966474563624` , `791145298072305685` , `791145926344966185` , `791146191336505414` , `791146355552682034` , `792565793568587796` , `795357387794939904` , `795358283623432213` , `798804993468530699` , `791146747367653387`);
            memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
            message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been Jailed for ${(ms(args[1]))}`);
 
            setTimeout(function () {
                memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(`791144820810842163` , `794825576602533898` , `791144908240060426` , `791144966474563624` , `791145298072305685` , `791145926344966185` , `791146191336505414` , `791146355552682034` , `792565793568587796` , `795357387794939904` , `795358283623432213` , `798804993468530699` , `791146747367653387`);
            }, ms(args[1]));
        } else{
            message.channel.send('Cant find that member!');
        }let cachedUserRoles = {};

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.guild.roles.cache.get`, `memberTarget.roles.remove`, and `memberTarget.roles.add` don't support multiple arguments. You need to add the roles into a list first then iterate over them.

```
const mainRoles = [`791144820810842163` , `794825576602533898` , `791144908240060426` , `791144966474563624` , `791145298072305685` , `791145926344966185` , `791146191336505414` , `791146355552682034` , `792565793568587796` , `795357387794939904` , `795358283623432213` , `798804993468530699` , `791146747367653387`];
module.exports = {
    name: `jail`,
    description: "this is jail command!",
    execute(message, args){
        
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(member){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);{
                if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send("You cant jail person because you are not staff/co owner/owner");
            }
            let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Jailed'); 
 
            if (!args[1]) {
                mainRoles.forEach(roleId => memberTarget.roles.remove(roleId));
                memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
                message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been Jailed`);
                return
            }
            mainRoles.forEach(roleId => memberTarget.roles.remove(roleId));
            memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
            message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been Jailed for ${(ms(args[1]))}`);
 
            setTimeout(function () {
                memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
                mainRoles.forEach(roleId => memberTarget.roles.add(roleId));
            }, ms(args[1]));
        } else{
            message.channel.send('Cant find that member!');
        }let cachedUserRoles = {};

        }
    }
```

Comment: so if I want to unmute and get the roles back, I just need to add the const mainroles to the unmute command?

Comment: @AnArWi Yes. Preferably, you would have a file to export `mainRoles` so that you only have one copy of the ids to deal with.